# How to stay in the modal overlay?

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation

I implemented Zurb's Foundation 5 into Wordpress. I want to have a modal popup for the login with ajax like that:

```
<a href="/wp-login.php" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-reveal-ajax="true">
    Login
</a>

<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
</div>
```

The login formula is being successfully loaded inside the `myModal` overlay div-container. However, when I enter a wrong password the modal div is closed and the usual wordpress login page is being loaded as usual with the password error message.

How can I force it to stay in the overlay mode until the login was successful?